# virtual box internet and lan not working with bridged network adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have Windows 7 host system on which i have installed virtual box. I have created a VM with Centos 6.8 installed. My problem is if I provide NAT and bridged network then Internet is working fine but local network sharing is not working, even ssh from other system is not working (I have provided necessary keys to both systems). now if change the network setting and remove NAT network adapter from virtual box settings then Local network sharing and ssh works fine but not internet. I want internet and local area network working on bridged network adapter only. can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the default gateway defined in the guest machine?

Comment: yes. everything is on DHCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes in virtual box as follows:

1) go to virtual box -> File -> preferences

2) select network tab -> host-only networks

3) select listed host-only network and click on edits selected host-only network icon

4) put adapter IPv4 address as follows:

IPv4 Address: 169.254.28.114
IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.0.0

5) click OK -> OK

Then reboot your VM, network should run properly.

My issue got resolved with this solution.

Thank you all...